# Pytest how to pass parameters/data between tests?

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to pass parameters between test cases.
I made a test case which is making post call with response `{"id":"5f985866f5532a52bb259926","name":"testName","desc":"","descData":null}`

I want to pass "id":"5f985866f5532a52bb259926" as a parameter to next test case.

What I have so far

```
@pytest.mark.first
def test_create_a_board():
    api_board = APIBoard()
    create_board = api_board.create_board_call(board_name='testName')
    Logger.LogInfo(f"creating a board named {create_board['name']}")


def test_create_3_cards_on_board():
    api_board = APIBoard()
    create_list = api_board.create_a_list_on_a_board_call()
```

def test_create_a_board returns

```
{"id":"5f985866f5532a52bb259926"}
```

How can I pass {"id":"5f985866f5532a52bb259926"} from the test_create_a_board to test_create_3_cards_on_board ? from the level of Pytest

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to have a test depend on the output of another. If you really want to do this, you have to use a gloval variable for that, but it would be better to refactor your tests to be independent of each other.

Comment: It's better to have that in one test, and use multiple asserts instead. Though I guess the best question would be to ask really "what is the thing I want to ensure" and capsulate that in single test.

Comment: @MrBean Bremen so If I need something from Post call in TC2 I should send the same POST call also in TC2?Also i remember when Used Behave I was using context for passing parameters through the steps and tc's

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a class- or module-scoped [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html) to create a variable to be shared by multiple tests:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def board():
    api_board = APIBoard()
    yield api_board.create_board_call(board_name="test_name")

def test_create_a_board(board):
    Logger.LogInfo(f"creating a board named {board['name']}")

def test_create_3_cards_on_board(board):
    create_list = board.create_a_list_on_a_board_call()
```

A few notes:

These look like they might be smoke tests (i.e. tests that just run without assertions to make sure nothing breaks), but you might consider adding assertions to your tests:

```py
def test_create_a_board(board):
    expected = {"expected": "output"}
    assert board['name'] == expected

def test_create_3_cards_on_board(board):
    create_list = board.create_a_list_on_a_board_call()
    assert create_list == ["whatever", "list"]
```

Also, unless these tests are specifically designed to test an external resource, you might consider mocking the API call's result.

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def mock_board():
    return {"board": "mock"}
```

Or consider using [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) to mock out the object you're trying to test.